# How To Add Babel Into Nuxt 3 Configuration?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to generate static pages using Nuxt 3 framework.

I had a Vue 3 project and now I need to convert it to Nuxt 3.

Everything is working fine, but I am not able to transpile code using Babel.

I was looking Nuxt docs, but I just cant find nothing there. I was also looking for some examples on Github, but without success.

Do someone had similar problem or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing similar migration right now `Vuetify 2`/`Nuxt 2` -> `Vuetify 3`/`Nuxt 3` and in the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/bundling) I could find `Remove any unused babel dependencies from your project.`. I've done that, and everything (so far) seems to be working completely fine without `Babel`.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt3 uses ViteJS. Vite is based on Parcel, so as [written here](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#babel), a `.babelrc` could be enough overall to be taken into account.
Otherwise, maybe give a try to [that one](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues?q=is%3Aissue+babel).
Also, you can join [Vite's discord](https://discord.com/invite/aYVNktYeEB) for a search/question, the team will gladly help you.